# Error connecting to a share folder from java

Tags: java, share, smb

I am working at an application in java which gets files from a share folder. For 2 days, i got same error trying to connect to the share folder. Until now, i didn't get this error. I dont know what is happened. Please help me.
My code:

```
package ScanPatch;

import java.util.TimerTask;

import Controllers.InterfataController;
import jcifs.smb.NtlmPasswordAuthentication;
import jcifs.smb.SmbFile;

public class MyTask extends TimerTask{

       public MyTask(){

       }

       @Override
       public void run() {

         //System.out.println("Hi see you after 10 seconds");
         for(int i=0;i<InterfataController.getListaCheckbox().size();i++)
            {
            String path="smb://bcr-hqb-w0935/Oracle/Patchuri/" + InterfataController.getListaCheckbox().get(i).getText() +"/";
            NtlmPasswordAuthentication userCred = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("BCRWAN",
                    "Sebastian.burchidrag", "Parola952491");
            SmbFile smbFile;
            jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.disablePlainTextPasswords","false");

            try {
                smbFile = new SmbFile(path, userCred);
                String [] patchuri=smbFile.list();
                if(patchuri.length>1)
                {
                    InterfataController.getListaCheckbox().get(i).setStyle("-fx-text-fill: red;");
                }
                else
                {
                    InterfataController.getListaCheckbox().get(i).setStyle("-fx-text-fill: black;");
                }
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }



       }

    }
```

The error is : **jcifs.smb.SmbException: 0xC000009A** on **String [] patchuri=smbFile.list();** this line.
The idea is that if a restart my computer, the application will work for the first connection, but only first time, then a i will get this error.

Comment: Could you post more complete code so we can test more thoroughly what it is you're trying to do? Could it be that the connection isn't being killed and the old instance is not letting a new one start up?

Comment: @px06, I edited my post. I have a hob which looks every 10 seconds in the share folder for files. I mean i scan to see when it appears a new file